# Working with 2 different tables and getting the latest/most recent values values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

Been struggling in Microsoft SQL a couple of hours with this.

I have 2 Tables.

```
Table1
ID | STOCK | STATUS
-----------------------------
1  | 1     | Out
2  | 1     | In
3  | 1     | Out
4  | 2     | Out
5  | 2     | In

Table2
ID | DATE
---------------
1  | 2013-07-01
2  | 2013-07-02
3  | 2013-07-03
4  | 2013-07-01
5  | 2013-07-02
```

I want to get the latest STOCK with the latest DATE and STATUS

-> Result must be

Result Table

```
ID| STOCK | STATUS | DATE
-------------------------------
3 | 1     | Out    | 2013-07-03
5 | 2     | In     | 2013-07-02
```

I have done the following:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.ID=Table2.ID
```

This joins the table but gives all 5 records. So I thought I would use the `MAX()` function like so

```
SELECT Table1.*, MAX(Table2.ID),Table2.Date  FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.ID=Table2.ID GROUP BY Table2.Date
```

But this does not run in the query windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.stock, t1.status, t5.mdate
FROM Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
inner join
(
   select t3.stock, max(t4.date) as mdate
   from table1 t3
   inner join Table2 t4 on t3.ID = t4.ID
   group by t3.stock
) t5 on t5.stock = t1.stock and t5.mdate = t2.date
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d26aa/2)

Comment: Should it be t3.max(date) or max(t3.date) ?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: +1 Can you please post JS Fiddle so that i can fiddle with your code :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Select t1.id,t1.stock,t1.status,t2.date
FROM Table1 as t1,Table2 as t2
Where t1.id=t2.id
Order By t2.date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your code works 99% but I forgot to state that I have MS SQL thus LIMIT is not implemented on my system. What alternative for LIMIT is there on MS SQL?

Comment: MS SQL TOP() is the equivalent to My Sql LIMIT

Comment: Select TOP 1 t1.id,t1.stock,t1.status,t2.date
FROM Table1 as t1,Table2 as t2
Where t1.id=t2.id
Order By t2.date DESC  -> When I run this I only get the first line returned, increasing value to TOP 5 for instance returns STOCK in 1-> 1-> 1-> 2-> ->2 Where I only want latest 1 -> 2 returned